# Why does unity wont let me do IL2CPP build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, linker, il2cpp

I got a problem in unity that wont let me to do build.
This is my error log :

```
Building C:\Users\Chenr\Documents\Unity Projects\NewMada\MDAProject\Library\Bee\artifacts\unitylinker_dwek.traceevents failed with output:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.23f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp\build\deploy\UnityLinker.exe --search-directory=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --out=Library/Bee/artifacts/WinPlayerBuildProgram/ManagedStripped --include-link-xml=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\MethodsToPreserve.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\TypesInScenes.xml --include-link-xml=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed\SerializedTypes.xml --include-link-xml=C:\Users\Chenr\Documents\Unity Projects\NewMada\MDAProject\Temp\burst.link.xml --include-link-xml=C:\Users\Chenr\Documents\Unity Projects\NewMada\MDAProject\Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\link.xml --include-directory=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Library/Bee/artifacts/unitylinker_dwek.traceevents --dotnetprofile=unityaot-win32 --dotnetruntime=Il2Cpp --platform=WindowsDesktop --use-editor-options --editor-settings-flag=None,Development --engine-modules-asset-file=C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.23f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WindowsStandaloneSupport/modules.asset --editor-data-file=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/EditorToUnityLinkerData.json --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/PhotonChat.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Unity.RenderPipelines.Universal.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Unity.TextMeshPro.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/PhotonRealtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/PhotonUnityNetworking.Utilities.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/PhotonUnityNetworking.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Unity.RenderPipelines.Core.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/SimpleFileBrowser.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Elringus.UnityGoogleDrive.Runtime.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/RTLTMPro.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/PhotonUnityNetworking.Demos.dll --include-unity-root-assembly=C:/Users/Chenr/Documents/Unity Projects/NewMada/MDAProject/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/DOTween.dll --print-command-line --enable-analytics
ILLink: error IL1999: ERROR: Failed to resolve base type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter for type Google.Apis.Json.RFC3339DateTimeConverter in assembly Google.Apis.Core.dll when linking against the UnityAot-Win32 profile
Fatal error in Unity CIL Linker
Unity.Linker.StrippingResolutionBaseTypeException: ERROR: Failed to resolve base type Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter for type Google.Apis.Json.RFC3339DateTimeConverter in assembly Google.Apis.Core.dll when linking against the UnityAot-Win32 profile
at Unity.Linker.MonoBehaviorUtilities.DerivesFrom(UnityLinkContext context, TypeDefinition type, String[] possibleBaseNames)
at Unity.Linker.MonoBehaviorUtilities.IsMonoBehaviourOrScriptableObject(UnityLinkContext context, TypeDefinition type)
at Unity.Linker.Steps.Rooting.ResolveFromMonoBehaviours.<Process>b__6_0(TypeDefinition t)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
at Unity.Linker.Steps.Rooting.ResolveFromMonoBehaviours.Process(LinkContext context)
at Unity.Linker.UnityPipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.UnityRun(Boolean noProfilerAllowed, ILogger customLogger)
at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriverWithoutErrorHandling(ILogger customLogger, Boolean noProfilerAllowed)
at Unity.Linker.UnityDriver.RunDriver()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [code stripping](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeStripping.html) might be stripping away the according constructor for that type because it is never explicitly used

-> Try to **preserve** that assembly explicitly in the `link.xml` (create if not exists) - see section `Annotate roots using a Link XML file` ->

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Google.Apis.Core"/>
</linker>
```

Comment: I manage to find the file and add the line but same error
 `<linker>
  <assembly fullname="mscorlib">
    <namespace fullname="System.Security.Cryptography" preserve="all"/>
  </assembly>
  <assembly fullname="System">
    <namespace fullname="System.Net.Configuration" preserve="all"/>
  </assembly>
  <assembly fullname="System">
    <namespace fullname="System.ComponentModel" preserve="all"/>
  </assembly>
  <assembly fullname="Photon3Unity3d">
    <namespace fullname="ExitGames.Client.Photon" preserve="all"/>
  </assembly>
 <assembly fullname="Google.Apis.Core"/>
</linker>`

Comment: hm though the docs say it's not needed you could try with the explicit `preserver="all"` attribute - though as said it should be implicit

Comment: I tried to added that so it looks like that (only for understanding) but I'm getting the same erros
```<assembly fullname="Google.Apis.Core" preserve="all"/>```

Comment: Ill added that i also tried to change from il2cpp to mono, same errors